# Eclipse plugin. Resolve variable + dynamic variables - doesn't work

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I tried to make an eclipse plugin and I had some difficulties.

First of all I created two extension points:

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.propertyPages">
    <page 
        id="com.coffee.projectPage" 
        name="Coffee Java Properties" 
        class="com.coffee.cona.properties.CoffeePropertyPage"> 
        <enabledWhen>
        <resolve variable="MYCOFFEE" args="">
            <equals value="cona"/>
        </resolve>
        </enabledWhen>
    </page> 
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.core.variables.dynamicVariables">
    <variable 
       name="MYCOFFEE"
       resolver="com.coffee.properties.CoffeeTimeResolver"
       description="Coffee time"
       supportsArgument="true">
    </variable> 
  </extension>
```

In my com.coffee.properties.CoffeeTimeResolver I wrote:

```
...

public class CoffeeTimeResolver implements IDynamicVariableResolver {

 public String resolveValue(IDynamicVariable variable, String argument){
  return "cona";
...
...
```

But it doesn't work! En Eclipse console I see this message:

```
!MESSAGE The variable MYCOFFEE is not defined
```

Where I was wrong?

---

All I need to do es show Property Page only in *.java files that have classes that extend Applet, I mean:

```
class Xxx extends Applet
```

but I really don't know how to reach it using test element

---

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse has a number of things referred to as variables.  `org.eclipse.core.variables.dynamicVariables` defines a dynamic string substitution variable, this is not the type of variable that the `resolve` element requires.

As far as I can see there is currently no way to define the `IVariableResolver` that `resolve` requires (but the Eclipse code is very large so I may have missed something).

You can probably use the `test` element instead and use the `org.eclipse.core.expressions.propertyTesters` extension point which definitely works properly.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer!!

I tried before to use variableResolver from org.eclipse.core.resources.variableResolvers
`code <extension
        point="org.eclipse.core.resources.variableResolvers">
     <variableResolver 
      class="com.coffee.properties.CoffeeTimeResolver2"
      name="MYCOFFEE">
    </variableResolver>
  </extension> `
but it also didn't help me of nothing way.

Comment: `org.eclipse.core.resources.variableResolvers` doesn't look like the correct sort of variable either. For what you want a property tester would be the correct thing to use - but working out that a Java file contains a class extending Applet is quite hard.